# Python column manipulation in a text file.

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, indexing

I have an input file:

```
A03 58  0   0   0   -9
A03 59  0   0   0   -9
A03 60  0   0   0   -9
A03 61  0   0   0   -9
A03 62  0   0   0   -9
A03 63  0   0   0   -9
A03 64  0   0   0   -9
A03 65  0   0   0   -9
A03 66  0   0   0   -9
A03 67  0   0   0   -9
A03 68  0   0   0   -9
A03 69  0   0   0   -9
A03 70  0   0   0   -9
A03 71  0   0   0   -9
A03 72  0   0   0   -9
A03 73  0   0   0   -9
A03 74  0   0   0   -9
```

My wanted output:

```
A03_58 A03_58 0 0 0 -9
A03_59 A03_59 0 0 0 -9
A03_60 A03_60 0 0 0 -9
```

The output will consider the second column in inputfile, add underscore to the first column and that letter. Then take that and copy it to the second column. 
I do know how to copy a column wit this:

```
# with open('inputfile.txt') as inputs:
#     for line in inputs:
#         parts = line.strip().split()
#         print("{0} {1}".format(parts[0], " ".join(parts)))
```

However, I need to change the column first and delete the second column before using above script.

I am not sure how to approach this after reading in the large input file. Browsed through some indexing questions, but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('in.txt') as in_, open('out.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ')

    for line in in_:
        row = line.split()
        first_col = '{}_{}'.format(row[0], row[1])
        writer.writerow([first_col, first_col] + row[2:])
```